# Missing argument label when calling a method in "strategy design pattern" -SWIFT

Tags: swift, design-patterns, methods, argument-passing, strategy-pattern

I am recently venture myself into Swift but I could not understand why my codes does not work when im returning an Int in a method.

```
protocol StrategyProtocol
{
    func calculate(num1:Int, num2:Int) ->Int
}

class Context
{
    var _strategyProtocol: StrategyProtocol!

    init(_strategyProtocol: StrategyProtocol)
    {
        self._strategyProtocol=_strategyProtocol
    }

    func Calculate(num1: Int, num2: Int) ->Int
    {
        return _strategyProtocol.calculate(num1, num2)
    }
}

class Add: StrategyProtocol
{
    func calculate(num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Int
    {
        return num1 + num2
    }
}

class Minus: StrategyProtocol
{
    func calculate(num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Int
    {
        return num1 - num2
    }
}
```

apparently this line of code does not work and prompt out **missing argument label 'num2:' in call**

```
//return _strategyProtocol.calculate(num1, num2)
```

can anyone show me how to fix it and explain to me.

Answer (score 1):

In Calculate func you are missing 2nd argument:

```
func Calculate(num1: Int, num2: Int) ->Int
  {
    return _strategyProtocol.calculate(num1, num2: num2)
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much.. but why do u include the num2: 
and you dont have to do it for num1?

Comment: Check out this link [http://www.objc.io/issues/16-swift/swift-functions/](http://www.objc.io/issues/16-swift/swift-functions/)